# Show existence of surjective homomorphism from ring of polynomials to ring of fractions with $\varphi(x)=1/t$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, ring-homomorphism

Let $ R $ be an integral domain, $ t\in R\backslash\{0\} $ and $ S=\{t^n:n\ge 0 \} $. Show that there exists a surjective ring homomorphism $ \varphi:R[x]\to S^{-1}R $ that satisfies $ \varphi(x)=\dfrac{1}{t} $.

I can find a surjective function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(x)=1/t$, but it is not a ring homomorphism. But anyway, I don't really need do find $\varphi$, I only need to prove its existence. I don't even know where to start. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$By the [universal property of polynomial rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring), there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi : R[x] \to S^{-1} R$ such that 
$$
\begin{cases}
\phi(r) = \dfrac{r}{1} & \text{for $r \in R$},\\
\\
\phi(x) = \dfrac{1}{t}.\\
\end{cases} 
$$
Clearly for $r \in R$ and $n \ge 0$
$$
\phi(r x^{n}) = \phi(r) \cdot \phi(x)^{n} = \frac{r}{t^{n}},
$$
hence $\phi$ is surjective.